# Swift call AnyClass class function

Tags: ios, swift

According to the article http://www.weheartswift.com/swift-objc-magic/
I create a NSObject extension to parse JSON string to object

```
import Foundation

extension NSObject {
    class func fromJson(jsonInfo: NSDictionary) -> Self {
        var object = self()

        (object as NSObject).load(jsonInfo)

        return object
    }

    func load(jsonInfo: NSDictionary) {
        for (key, value) in jsonInfo {
            let keyName = key as String

            if (respondsToSelector(NSSelectorFromString(keyName))) {
                setValue(value, forKey: keyName)
            }
        }
    }

    func propertyNames() -> [String] {
        var names: [String] = []
        var count: UInt32 = 0
        var properties = class_copyPropertyList(classForCoder, &count)
        for var i = 0; i < Int(count); ++i {
            let property: objc_property_t = properties[i]
            let name: String = String.fromCString(property_getName(property))!
            names.append(name)
        }
        free(properties)
        return names
    }

    func asJson() -> NSDictionary {
        var json:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [:]

        for name in propertyNames() {
            if let value: AnyObject = valueForKey(name) {
                json[name] = value
            }
        }


        return json
    }

}
```

I create a Class inherited NSObject

```
import Foundation

class Weather : NSObject {

    var date : String = ""
    var currentCity : String = ""
    var weather : String = ""
    var wind : String = ""
    var dayPictureUrl : String = ""
    var nightPictureUrl : String = ""
    var temperature : String = ""
}
```

then I build a helper to get API and parse result to Object

```
func requestApi(url :String, returnType: AnyClass, success: (res: AnyObject)->() ){
    var queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
    var group = dispatch_group_create()

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue) { () -> Void in
        var url = NSURL.init(string:url)
        var data = NSData.init(contentsOfURL:url!)

        let jsonObj: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,error:nil)

        if let topDict = jsonObj as? NSDictionary {
            var obj : AnyObject = returnType.fromJson(topDict)
            success(res: obj);
        }
    }    
}
var api : String = "http://somesite.com/jsonapi"

requestApi(api, Weather.self, { (res) -> () in
     // finish get the res obj
})
```

I know how to do it use Objective-C
but Swift I get this error at this line

```
LINE : var obj : AnyObject = returnType.fromJson(topDict)
ERROR : 'AnyClass' does not h``ave a member named from JSON
```

I don't know a lot about Swift,
I only want to call returnType class function ,
how can I do it ?

Comment: `AnyClass`? Maybe you meant `AnyObject`. But this is only part of your problem.

Comment: I write more detail I want to pass a type to function and return a instance of this type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `returnType` is declared as being `AnyClass`. So of course it does not have a member fromJson. Probably you need to declare is as a class type that has this method.

Comment: but I want it is a universal function, I pass a type to the  function and it return a instance of this type

Comment: Then you need to cast it on use to be that class which contains fromJson.

Comment: fromJson is a extension of NSObject and it is from http://www.weheartswift.com/swift-objc-magic/

Comment: Then use `(returnType as NSObject).fromJson` or simply declare it as being NSObject instead of AnyClass.

Comment: I did it yesterday but I get this Error : 'NSObject' does not have a member named 'fromJson' .

Comment: I just saw that fromJson is an instance method. So you need to use it as such.

Comment: I added more code detail, fromJson is a class method.

Comment: Have you seen my edited comment? You can only call `NSObject.fromJson` and get an NSObject as result. It's an instance method.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I saw ur comment then I call NSObject.fromJson and get no Error, but fromJson method create a NSObject instance not my input type

Comment: So probable you should call `var obj : AnyObject = returnType.load(topDict)` instead?

Comment: Yes~ but I got error~ I want know if i get pass type how to use the type call class func

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. If you need an object as result then call fromJson. If you just want to load a json in your existing object then call `(returnType as NSObject).load`

Comment: Hi Thomas~Thanks a lot, I already fix it, at last I use generic function to make it run, the function is : func requestApi<T: NSObject>(url :String, returnType: T, success: (res: T)->() ){ ... }